# How to avoid creating function/method with many parameters?

Tags: php

Supposed I have method of repository class like this to create post:

```
 public function create($title, $slug, $custom_slug = '', $meta_keyword, $body, $meta_description, $status, $bla, $bla)
```

is there any way to avoid this in the right way? because I think it is not good if there are many parameters and not really readable. i often put the value in wrong place since i dont remember the parameters orders.

if I set parameter as array like this:

```
public function create(array $columns)
```

but client won't know which required parameters and which one is not.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can get around this problem by passing in your arguments as an array. Alternatively, you can make the parameters public static fields, so that they can be accessed from within your method without you having to even pass them in as parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class like this:

```
class Post {
    protected $title;
    protected $body;
    protected $slug;
    protected $metaKeyword; 
    protected $metaDescription;
    protected $status;

    function __construct($title, $body) {
        $this->setTitle($title);
        $this->setBody($body);
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function setBody($body) {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function setSlug($slug) {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }

    public function setMetaKeyword($metaKeyword) {
        $this->metaKeyword = $metaKeyword;
    }

    public function setMetaDescription($metaDescription) {
        $this->metaDescription = $metaDescription;
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function save() {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

---

```
$post = new Post('Example', 'This is a body');
$post->setSlug('example-post');
$post->save();
```